# How serious is this warning about extension cords?

Tags: extension-cord

My AC came with this scary warning -- but the outlet is really not convenient and I'd like to use an extension cord. Not a power strip, just a 3ft simple extension cord. Electrical consumption is not given,

> Cooling - Rated Cooling Amps AHAM, 11.4.

> Cooling - Watts, 1260

But I doubt that's the real power consumption. I don't have a kill-a-watt to test. However, the extension cord I am looking at is "3 Feet 14 AWG UL Listed 1875W". I really would like to avoid electrical fires, obviously.

[image]

Comment: With a high quality extension cord there is little risk.  14 guage is technically adequate for 15A if you disregard the warning, but for large loads, I instinctively derate to 12.  In the event of death, fire or electrical shock if it is demonstrable that you used equipment against a warning or just outside it's intended use, you may find your insurance void, *especially if misuse is deemed to be the cause of the accident*.  Depending on the unit, it may be better to install a longer extension cord to keep the number of pressurized contact connections down to two.

Comment: Or use Legrand Wiremold surface conduit and some THHN wire to extend off the existing receptacle to a new one in a better location.

Comment: If you do use an extension cord, make it as short as possible and do not coil the cord. The coiled cord will have less air cooling and will more easily overheat.

Comment: @DoxyLover 310.15(B)(3)(a), but with a cord in open air lol.

Comment: Feel the cord after it's been running for an hour or so; if it's hot, no good. If it's just a little warm, probably ok, but check after more time.

Answer (score 4):

You say the electrical consumption is not given but you list it at 1260w that is how much it draws.

The problem with most extension cords is the molded ends.
The cord ends get hot and melt this is when there is the greatest risk of a shock , or fire.

A few years ago I had some unhappy folks at my plant when I collected all the plug expanders they were using, I told them if they needed additional receptacles to submit a request and I would pull new circuits.

The grumbling was enough I took one of the plug expanders and ran it up on my test bed and monitored the heat. At the plant all of the circuits and my plan was to slowly load the plug expanders starting at 10 amps and run them up to 20. None of them made it to 20 amps, simple resistance load every one melted down by 18 amps and several as low as 14 amps.

This was much worse than I expected so I pulled some extension cords off the floor and ran the same test 14 & 12 gauge cords I had similar results with the extension cords (slow ramp to 10-15 amps then ramp to 15-20 total time 1 hour 2 failed this test. I then took my spec grade cord caps and repeated the test and the 3 cords I tested did not fail ( cord from failed 14&12 awg test and a 14 awg soow).
I was curious if the cord caps would hold up a bit further and ran all 3 to 25 amps they were getting warm but they did not fail like the molded ones.
Yes I ran #14 to 25 amps.

So I would not use a standard duty extension cord because of the ac unit running for hours on end (although I did not have failures in 1 hour at that low wattage ) if there was a problem and you try and remove the plug and the thermoplastic plug comes apart that could be dangerous as advertised.

Comment: Great to have experimental evidence! What do you mean by a "cord cap"? Is it the extension cord ends which have screw terminals inside and clamp onto the cable?

Comment: I really have no idea whether cooling -- watts means the actual watts drawn from the wall when in cooling mode or so some fancy made up process measuring how much cooling happens and then efficiency enters the equation and it would draw more from the wall.

Comment: The real issue is that extension cords with 15 A plugs have 16 AWG conductors or even smaller. When they should be 14 AWG to prevent this exact type of overheating

Comment: Fascinating, Ed. I'm certainly not intending to post this as a answer, but am curious if a type S or SJ cable with heavy duty plug and receptacle (the screw/clamp types) would fare in your testing.

Comment: @Mathew boutique yes I use commercial grade cord caps like 5269C & 5266C these are heavy duty compared to most and are not destroyed with air filled tires running over them, a solid tire will take them out but that usually damages the cord also,

Comment: @ratchet freak yes some cords are 16 awg  but the wire size is not the problem it is usually the molded plug that fails, I tested 14 awg up to 25 amps with my cord caps and it did fine but they were failing with the factory molded plug. See table 400.5A.1 16 awg cord is rated for 13 amps if the 80% rule is followed as UL listing requires a 16 awg cord will have the ampacity required to supply a standard device.

Comment: @grorge Anderson I used type SOOW with screw clamp 5266C & 5269C. Type SJ the insulation is not as heavy, I would expect it to preform the same, can’t handle rough treatment because of thinner insulation.  Most of my cords are extra hard duty 14 awg for use around the mill but I do have up to 500 amp 3 phase pin and sleeve but I doubt I will ever try to do overload testing on those the breakers can be scary enough when they fail the 20 minute ramp test. My findings was that the plug was the weak point. If connecting to a builders grade receptacles they would probably fail at a lower ampacity.

Comment: *files away model number*

Comment: Note my original post contained the extension cord I was looking at is 14 AWG.

Comment: I think you finally convinced me that one of these days when I get around to a bunch of fixups around the house, that I'll add another duplex receptacle at the kitchen sit-down counter. Always a 3-in-1 extender plugged in because of phone chargers, etc. I never liked the way it looked hanging there, but now you've convinced me it is a hazard waiting to be activated. Fortunately normal usage is just a couple of USB chargers.

Comment: @EdBeal this looks to be _very_ thorough and _very_ useful info. Unfortunately, we're not all electricians and some of the terms are a bit difficult for us laymen. If you would expand this with additional details (or even pictures) of what you're referring to, that would make this a _even more_ useful answer to a broader audience. Obviously, a lot of people need convincing and "dumbing it down" would help tremendously. (You've already got my +1, I'd give more for additional info if I could.)

Answer (score 2):

Physically:
If you use a correct 3 wire extension cord with correct wire gauge, everything will be ok.
However,
manufacturers love to put an "must be plugged into receptacle" note on their equipment, so they can easily skip on warranty shall something happen (my heater has the same warranty rule).

Fix:
What you can do (check local code!), is to put a surface-mount wall socket, and run a wire on top of the wall to nearest receptacle, then hardwire it in (drill or file a nick under existing socket, fish the cable in and connect it on back of the socket).
It is now a proper socket you can plug your device in, because there is no rule a socket has to be embedded in the wall and that cables have to be inside wall. They look less pretty, but are perfectly safe if done correctly. Contact your electrician if you need help with it.

What not to do:
Do not splice the existing cord or replace it - this will void the appliance warranty.

Comment: You'll need some sort of wire mold surface conduit and the associated cover plates.

Comment: That depends on country electrical code. You can use dedicated cable 'staples' to run cable along the wall.